# o2micro SD-Card-Reader doesn't work: how to edit *.conf?

Tags: 18.04, sd-card, timeout, mmc

I've got Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a Dell E7250. The o2-micro-SD-card-reader doesn't work after installation so I have to do

```
sudo rmmod sdhci_pci
sudo rmmod sdhci
sudo modprobe sdhci debug_quirks2="0x80000000"
sudo modprobe sdhci_pci
```

at startup.

The blog post [Workaround for broken O2 Micro SD card reader support since Linux kernel version 4.1.8](https://www.0xf8.org/2016/01/workaround-for-broken-o2-micro-sd-card-reader-support-since-linux-kernel-version-4-1-8/) says that I have to edit a `*.conf` file to have it happen automatically at startup, but it doesn't say which file and how exactly I have to edit it.

What file do I have to edit?

Answer (score 0):

If you can find `sdhci.conf`, you can copy the code into that file. But I'm unable to locate `sdhci.conf` where I've been told it should be, e.g., `/etc/modprobe.d/sdhci.conf`.